# Swift -How to scroll the collectionView's contents when the keyboard is raised

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, keyboard-events

This isn't a question about raising the collectionView when the keyboard rises and lowers, that part works fine. This is about the scrollView inside the collectionView not rising with it.

I have a view pinned to the bottom of the screen and inside that view I have a textView. Pinned to the top of the view is a collectionView that's pinned to the top of the screen

```
-top of viewController
    collectionView
    containerView that contains a textView
-bottom of viewController
```

When the textView's textField is tapped I use a notification which detects when the keyboard rises and lowers. It works fine because the collectionView goes up and down like it's supposed to. The problem is the collectionView's contents. If the collectionView's cells fill the screen when the collectionView rises up it's scrollVIew doesn't raise with it so the the cells are behind the keyboard. 2 pics below.

When the keyboard notification is sent I tried changing the collectionView's contentInset, scrollIndicatorInsets, and tried scrolling to the last cell but nothing. The cells just scroll up a tad bit.

```
@objc fileprivate func keyboardWillShow(notification: Notification) {

    guard let keyboardDuration = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? Double else { return }
    guard let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else { return }

    let keyboardFrame = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
    let keyboardHeight = keyboardFrame.height

    containerViewBottomAnchorConstraint?.isActive = false
    containerViewBottomAnchorConstraint = containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -keyboardHeight)
    containerViewBottomAnchorConstraint?.isActive = true

    // I tried this
    let item = tableData.count - 1
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: 0)
    if !tableData.isEmpty {
        collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
    }

    // I tried this
    let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: -keyboardHeight, right: 0)
    collectionView.contentInset = contentInsets
    collectionView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

    UIView.animate(withDuration: keyboardDuration, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }) { [weak self](_) in
        self?.autoScrollToLastCell() // I tried this
    }
}

@objc fileprivate func keyboardWillHide(notification: Notification) {

    guard let keyboardDuration = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? Double else { return }

    containerViewBottomAnchorConstraint?.isActive = false
    containerViewBottomAnchorConstraint = containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
    containerViewBottomAnchorConstraint?.isActive = true

    UIView.animate(withDuration: keyboardDuration, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }) { [weak self](_) in
        self?.autoScrollToLastCell()
    }
}

func autoScrollToLastCell() {
    let section = 0
    let item = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: section) - 1
    let index = IndexPath(item: item, section: section)
    if item > 0 {
        collectionView.scrollToItem(at: index, at: .bottom, animated: true)
    }
}
```

**Before the keyboard rises**
[image]

**After the keyboard rises the collectionView is up but it's contents aren't**
[image]

Comment: `-keyboardHeight` I think it should be positive

Comment: Hey thanks. I tried that already but it didn’t work.

Answer (score 4):

This should be the accepted answer:

Add the listener when the keyboard is raised:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
```

Then add this function:

```
@objc func handleKeyboardWillShow(notification: Notification) {

            collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(row: messagesList.count - 1, section: chatSection), at: .top, animated: false)
    }
```

Note: If you have more than one section, change the `section` value

Comment: I’ll try it tomorrow but explain to me why my answer is in correct when I’ve used it with 1 message that says “hello” to 50 messages that have different cells sizes and I haven’t had 1 problem with my answer. If what you’re saying my answer is incorrect then I should have all sorts problems but I don’t have any. How is that possible?

Comment: Someone remove one of my original comments. I’ll leave again

Comment: Your answer might be correct for your particular situation, because what you needed was indeed the padding, however, the original question was formulated on scrolling the collection view when the keyboard is raised

Comment: @@Andrea please read my answer, I never said the 8 point padding is what fixed the issue. Look at the very first sentence, it says “all I had to do was set the collectionView’s content inset”. The second sentence says “8 points just so it appears that the last cell can have padding”. I used the word “appears”. I never said the 8 points is what fixed my issue.

Comment: No your incorrect about that because even if the contentInset is 0,0,0,0 it works fine. The issue was when the keyboard rose the content was still underneath the keyboard. Once I set the contentInset the content was no longer behind the keyboard it was where it was supposed to be. The padding just made it rise. Without it without the padding it worked. Why do you keep saying the padding fixed the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Changing to **keyboardDidShow** might solve the problem because **keyboardWillShow** is called when the keyboard is showing up.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardDidShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
```

Adding the function will help to scroll the view to the bottom.

```
@objc func keyboardDidShow() {
    self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: [0, messageList.count - 1],
                                     at: .bottom,
                                     animated: false)
}
```