# How to move up collection view controller when keyboard appears?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a collection view I made in storyboard and a container view with text field constrained to the bottom of the view programmatically. However, when I show the keyboard the collection view stays hidden underneath and I'm not sure how to. I looked and most answers say to use self.view.frame.origin.y in the keyboard notification listener but that's hasn't worked for me.

my keyboard notification code

```html
    @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        let keyboardFrame = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
        let duration = ((notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber)?.doubleValue)!
        
        containerViewbottomAnchor?.constant = -keyboardFrame!.height

        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
        
    }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

first image is the normal chat and second is the max view you ca see when the keyboard is shown. the container view contains the textfield and button which I added programmatically. they are within an input accessory view to update their positions when the keyboard comes up.

Comment: what is `containerViewbottomAnchor` ?

Comment: and log `keyboardFrame` in this function ... make sure you are getting height

Comment: can you check with this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/56802182/7301439

Comment: i edited the original to show some more pictures of the container view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by changing to a UICollectionview controller class

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57438748/13042987

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)


@objc func handleKeyboardWillShow(notification: Notification) {

        collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(row: messagesList.count - 1, section: chatSection), at: .top, animated: false)
}
```

Comment: '@objc func handleKeyboardDidShow() {
        if messages.count > 0 {
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(item: messages.count - 1, section: 0)
            collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath as IndexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
        }
    }' yeah this works for taking the user to the bottom but the keyboard still overlaps